# Variable amount of function arguments in C++

Tags: c++, function, arguments

So, in C the standard way is stdarg.h. But I'm looking to pull up something a bit like this:

```
template<int A>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(...) {
        // fill each value of array with an argument.
    };

    virtual ~MyClass() { };
private:
    float array[A];
};
```

Obviously, the idea is not to have different constructions for every possible amount of arguments. Any suggestions, standard ways, whatsoever?

Thanks,

Julian.

Comment: Pass a container or use std::initialize_list if you have that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 you can use an [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) constructor for this kind of scenario. That allows for this type of initialization:

```
MyClass<5> x{1,2,3,4,5};
```

although you have to define what happens when the dimensions do not match. But for these kinds of statically sized arrays, it is worth looking at [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). These have a well defined behaviour when the dimensions of the initializer don't match their own.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `initializer_list`

```
explicit MyClass(std::initializer_list<T> list_args){
    // fill each value of array with an argument.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to C++11 initializer_lists you can just pass a vector.

```
MyClass(const std::vector& values) {
    //copy values into array
};

MyClass someClass( std::vector<int>(10,4) ); //adds 10x 4 to the vector
```